# Bootstrap grid - nested rows and cols causes div scrollbar to break

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a strange issue trying to implement a scrollbar (i.e. `stlye=overflow-y:auto;`) on divs which contain the Bootstrap `row` and `col` classes.

So the basic question is: why aren't the scroll bars working when the columns are displayed side-by-side; and of course, how can I get scroll bars working properly.

Here is the plunker which I've created to reproduce the problem:
[bootstrap nested rows](https://plnkr.co/edit/14FxGzuAZoiCkjPYiYil?p=preview)

```
 http://plnkr.co/edit/14FxGzuAZoiCkjPYiYil?p=preview
```

**Two scenarios:**

**1) Scroll bars not working**

If you widen the browser window enough, then the nested `row` under `<div id="left" class="col-md-6 " >` will pan to the left - and scroll bars DO NOT WORK.

**2) Scroll bars working**
If you narrow the browser window further, you'll see that all my divs will stack on top of one another - and the scroll bars are back working.

Here's the same html grid code in the plunker above:

```html
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row" > 
   <div id="left" class="col-md-6 " >
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 section-left">
                 <strong>First Column, First Cell</strong>
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...   
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...   
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                with more text...with more text...with more text...
                with more text...with more text...with more text...
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
            </div>
           <div class="col-md-12  section-left">
                 <strong>Second Column, First Cell</strong>
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...   
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...   
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                 with more text...with more text...with more text...
                with more text...with more text...with more text...
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
                with more text...with more text...with more text... 
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="right" class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12  section-right" >
             Second Column, First Cell...Second Column, First Cell...Second Column, First Cell...                       
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12  section-right">
             Second Column, Second Cell
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12  section-right">
             Second Column, Third Cell
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the scoped css:

```css
<style scoped>
    
   
    .section-left {
        height:100px;border:1px solid; margin-left: 15px; overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .section-right {
        height:100px;border:1px solid; margin-left: 15px; overflow-y:auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `margin-left` for .section-left and .section-right is causing this to happen

Remove this in you CSS.

```
margin-left: 15px;
```